# Symfony2 Mongodb aggregate - get max value for a field

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-odm

Want to get the max value of the field `speed` and its corresponding other fields for this record.

Have this MongoDB query:

```
db.Neo.aggregate({
    $group: {
        _id: '$name',
        date: { $first: '$date' },
        neo_reference_id: { $first: '$neo_reference_id' },
        name: { $first: '$name' },
        speed: {
            $max: "$speed"
        },
        is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid: { $first: '$is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid' }        
    }        
});
```

Now since I am using Symfony2 and mongo-odm-aggregation-bundle, want to get this query executed:

```
public function neofastestAction() {

    $expr = new \Solution\MongoAggregation\Pipeline\Operators\Expr;
    $aq = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb.odm.default_aggregation_query')->getCollection('NeoNasaBundle:Neo')->createAggregateQuery();

    $result = $aq->group(['_id'=>'$name' ])
        ->getQuery()->aggregate()->toArray();        
    $serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer');
    $response = $serializer->serialize($result,'json');
    return new Response($response);
}
```

This executes it, but prints only the `_id`. How do I build my MondoDB query from above into Symfony2 mongo-odm-aggregation-bundle (https://packagist.org/packages/solution/mongo-odm-aggregation-bundle) and get the last row? It should be the highest value of `speed`, so the fastest asteroid.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This does it:

```
public function neofastestAction() {

      $expr = new \Solution\MongoAggregation\Pipeline\Operators\Expr;
      $aq = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb.odm.default_aggregation_query')->getCollection('NeoNasaBundle:Neo')->createAggregateQuery();

      $result = $aq->group(['_id'=>'$name', 'date'=> $expr->first('$date'),  'neo_reference_id'=> $expr->first('$neo_reference_id'), 'name'=> $expr->first('$name'), 'speed'=> $expr->max('$speed'),'is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid'=> $expr->first('$is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid') ])
             ->sort(['speed' => -1])->limit(1)->getQuery()->aggregate()->toArray();


      $serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer');
      $response = $serializer->serialize($result,'json');

      return new Response($response);
    }
```